# Count users with big space between pings logic

Tags: signal-processing, estimation, sampling, error-propagation

please try to be lenient with me because I really have forgotten most of the stuff, so I will probably be making incorrect assumptions, word the problem incorrectly, etc.

## Context

I'm trying to calculate the amount of daily users an application has. Currently the application sends a ping to the servers if at least 24 hours have passed since the last ping.

It needs to be taken into account that the application might not send a signal if it's not switched on. Examples:

- The application is opened for the first time, ping is sent immediately
- The application is opened for 24h and 1 second, a ping is sent at the beginning and at the 24th hour
- The application is opened and closed, and opened again after 8 hours, a ping is sent only the first time
- The application is opened and closed, and opened again after 30 hours, a ping is sent the first time, and at hour 30

The pings are summed on a daily basis and presented as the daily users the application has. I will refer to this as daily signal.

## Questions

My objective is to understand:

- How the original signal (users using the application) is transformed by the different design decisions to arrive to the daily users number.
- If and where does [Nyquist–Shannon sampling theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) apply.

  - I have failed to understand what happens when a signal has higher frequency than a the sampling its being measured with, and what does this mean to when reconstructing the signal. From what I understand, a lot of aliasing is introduced, however I don't see how it can't be dealt with in this scenarios.
- How to calculate the error of the final output VS the desired output (users that pinged in a day VS users active in a day)

Comment: "reconstructing a daily signal would require to have at least a sampling frequency of 12 hours" makes no sense. What does a "daily signal" mean? If you want to reconstruct a signal with a sampling frequency of 12 hours, the signal must have a bandwidth of at most 1/(12*3600) Hz (that's a reeeeaaaalllyyyy slowly varying signal - there is no signal of practical interest that would be sampled with such a low sampling frequency). If you want to apply Nyquist theory, you need to know the bandwidth of the signal you are sampling. Seems to me you don't have a good understanding of your problem.

Comment: @Stelios thanks for your response, your closing remark is maybe too aggressive comment to someone asking for help. I actually don't understand the problem. From my limited understanding of the problem, the signal has infinite bandwidth by the step nature of the parts (either a user is online or not, and all the sums of the parts make the signal). This means that any sampling (a ping every 24 hours) will directly introduce a limit on the bandwith that can be measured (24h period). I have no idea how to approach this problem. I will try to extend update the problem description.

Comment: @Stelios from your statement I understand that sampling a signal outside of the Nyquist frequency (which seems to be the case because a daily measurement doesn't mean the signal has a daily period) is not covered by nyquist. I have rewriten the problem so that it's more clear the things I understand and the things I don't.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I am understanding correctly,

- There is a system where users enter and, I suppose, leave after using it for some time (this is a, so called, queue)
- The number of users in the system is sampled with some (maybe non-uniform) frequency
- You want to find the number of users that entered the system within a 24h interval given the samples

I don't see how the sampling theorem is relevant here. As you pointed out, the process you are trying to reconstruct is discontinuous (infinite bandwidth) and the sampling theorem does not apply here.

I think it is impossible to give a definite answer for the number of users with gaps between measurements. You can only hope to provide a probabilistic answer, i.e., something of the form "given the measurements, the number of users within 24h was 10 with probability p(10), 11 with probability p(11), and so on."

The only approach I can think of is to consider a stochastic model for the arrival and departure of users in the system, which  will provide a probabilistic characterization of the number of users entering the system in any given interval, without any measurements. Given the measurements, you would consider the conditional probabilities (i.e., if you sampled, say, 8 users at some instant during the interval of interest, the probability of the number of users being less than 8 is zero, although there might be a non-zero probability that this will be the case if no measurements are available.)

You could maybe start by the simplest mathematical model for the arrival times in a queue, the Poisson point process. This however, does not model how long the users stay in the system (i.e., when they depart). You should look into queueing theory for such models.

P.S.: Apologies if I came off as offensive in my comment, that was not my intention.

Comment: For further clarification, there is no queue, but rather there is a pool of users with the application open, which I guess their use of the application will follow a Poisson distribution. Each of them is individually reporting their belonging to the pool every time 24 hours have passed since the last report, which might be longer if the application was not opened. Therefore there is not an instant where all users report activity. From your message, I would need to model user stay, and then calculate of the probability of users from the previous day carrying over to the next one?

Comment: Also, regarding the apology, no worries, it took me a bit for surprise but I'm happy it was a misunderstanding